# Cannot read property 'onBoundsChanged' of undefined

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I write a extension for google chrome I got error as title question. Below is my code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "libs/jquery.js"
}, function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: "src/content.js"
    });
});
});

chrome.app.window.onBoundsChanged.addListener(function (tab) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "libs/jquery.js"
}, function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: "src/content.js"
    });
});
});
```

Firstly, I got success with onClicked event. But I want extension work when I resized window. But when I add 2nd event. Error occur

Please help me this error
Thank you

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Bootstrap Grid for any Website",
"version": "1.1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Quickly toggle a Bootstrap Grid for any website. Easy to use, easy success.",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "src/icon48.png"
},
"background" : {
"scripts" : [
  "src/background.js"
]
},
"content_scripts": [
{
  "js":         [ "src/send_value.js" ],
  "matches":    [ "<all_urls>" ],
  "all_frames": true,
  "run_at":     "document_end"
}
],
"permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your extension folder look like:

[image: Folder strucrure]

Your `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "Bootstrap Grid for any Website",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Quickly toggle a Bootstrap Grid for any website. Easy to use, easy success.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "src/icon48.png"
  },
  "background" : {
    "scripts" : [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources":[
    "src/content",
    "src/content_temp",
    "libs/jquery.js"
  ]

}
```

`background.js`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: "libs/jquery.js"
    }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: "src/content.js"
        });
    });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message){
    if(message.info !== 1) return;

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: "src/content_temp.js"
    });
});
```

And your `send_value.js` file I put into `content.js`:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function (e) {
    // here you send message to background.js
    var message = {info: 1}
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage("", message);
});


function devTool() {
```

As for me, it works fine! :-)

Comment: I changed to 

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
to pass warning from google store. 
Anw, Thank you for your spirit. Again again and again. I do not see many person like you in my life. You have my respect. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you've mixed up chrome extensions and chrome apps. As we can read [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window), `chrome.app.window` is

> not associated with any Chrome browser windows

I recommend you create content.js script where you put something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e){
  ....
   // here you send message to background.js
   var message = { info: "window resized");
   chrome.runtime.sendMessage( "", message );
})
```

`content.js` must be executed in every tab you specified in manifest file.

In your background.js you should write:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message){
   if(message.info === "window resized"){
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, // ..... the stuff you've written above
      ......
   }
});
```

Links:

[chrome.runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage)

[chrome.runtime.onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)

Good luck!

UPD (in manifest file):

```
      "background": { 
            "scripts": [ "background.js"]
        },
       "content_scripts": [
         {
           "js":         [ "content.js" ],
           "matches":    [ "<all_urls>" ],
           "all_frames": true,
           "run_at":     "document_end"
         }
      ],
```

UPD 2. This snippet is from my working extension manifest:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "main.js",
    "style.css",
    "options/options.css",
    "options/options.js"
  ]
```

Comment: "background" : {
    "scripts" : [
      "src/background.js",
      "src/content.js"
    ]
  },

is it right

Comment: Look at the UPD in post above.

Comment: Another concern about matches in content_scripts. I got "Broad host permissions" when upload to google store even I specify the "matches" to "http://*/*". Do you have exp about this

Comment: Try match to "\*://\*"

Comment: Is there any way to run extension correctly without define content_script with matches . Because I want my extension run in any kind of website. localhost, local html file ...... Below is current manifest file content.
`  "background" : {
    "scripts" : [
      "src/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js":         [ "src/send_value.js" ],
      "matches":    [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "all_frames": true,
      "run_at":     "document_end"
    }
 ],
  "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}`

Comment: It is hard to me to detect the bug, "<all urls>" pattern runs content.js in every tab, including html files from hdd.
"when upload to google store" - you mean https://store.google.com? If so, it looks like ordinary site with secured http protocol... But, do you try to load something using content.js? In such a case you have to specify it in web accessible resourses. Look at UPD above again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I have added manifest.json above. if I define send_value.js (send mess function) in web_accessible_resource. It does not work. You can have look on my git hub. not too many code lines. https://github.com/thanhtam282/Bootstrap-Grid-Chorme-Extension.
And my extension in store (old version)
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bootstrap-grid-for-any-we/ngjnlpkfccnglmlobafmobgjoiiliden?hl=en-US